# Mathematical function a of an integrator in series with a non inverting op amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, series, output, modeling, integrator

I am trying to understand the circuit given below so I can make a mathematical model of it.

[image]

The circuit consists of an integrator with a reference (offset) voltage and a non inverting op amp connected in series. All of the parameters are constant except *Vin = Vin(t)*, *VoutB = VoutB(t)* and *VoutA = VoutA(t)*. They are a function of time. Also, lets assume that both of the op amps are rail-to-rail for simplicity. I estimated the output voltage function of *OpAmpB* to be:

$$V_{outB}(t) = \Bigg(1+{R_f\over R_{inB}}\Bigg)Vin(t)\tag{1}$$
with the limitation:
$$0 \leq V_{outB}(t) \leq V_{powB} - 5.1V\tag{2}$$

I assume that the limitation above exists because of the Zener diode. I found out that at this link: [Zener diode at inverter op amp's output](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/397638/zener-diode-at-inverter-op-amps-output). Next, I estimated the output function of the integrator to be:

$$V_{outA}(t)  = V_{ref} + {1 \over R_{inA}C_f}\int_0^t{\Big(V_{ref} - V_{outB}(t)\Big)dt}\tag{3}$$

Since *Vref* is a constant, I estimated the mathematical function of the integrator to be:
$$V_{outA}(t)  = V_{ref} +{V_{ref} \over R_{inA}C_f}t - {1 \over R_{inA}C_f}\int_0^t{V_{outB}(t)dt}\tag{4}$$

Finally, by substituting equation (1) into equation (4), I got the final expression for the output voltage of the circuit:

$$V_{outA}(t)  = V_{ref} +{V_{ref} \over R_{inA}C_f}t - {\bigg(1+{R_f\over R_{inB}}\bigg) \over R_{inA}C_f}\int_0^t{V_{in}(t)dt}\tag{5}$$

with the following limitations:

$$0 \leq V_{in}(t) \leq {{V_{powB} - 5.1V}\over \bigg(1+{R_f\over R_{inB}}\bigg)}\tag{6}$$
$$0 \leq V_{outA}(t) \leq V_{powA}\tag{7}$$

The problem is, I do not know how does the resistor *Ro* effects the output voltage *VoutA(t)*. To me that resistor seems like it does not effect the circuit so it is not in the mathematical model of it. Am I wrong? If yes, can somebody please explain to me why? Also, does the Zener diode effect the output voltage *VoutA(t)* in any other way except the limitation of the *opAmpB* output voltage?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *The problem is, I do not know how does the resistor Ro effects the
> output voltage VoutA(t). To me that resistor seems like it does not
> effect the circuit so it is not in the mathematical model of it. Am I
> wrong?*

Your analysis of Ro is correct. It represents a load on the op-amp output and it's not a very hungry load so can be largely ignored. If it were below 1 kΩ I'd start to be concerned but it's 10 kΩ and shouldn't really be a problem.

> *Also, does the Zener diode effect the output voltage VoutA(t) in any
> other way except the limitation of the opAmpB output voltage?*

It limits the ability of the op-amp (B) to drive large positive voltages onto the Vout node but, given that the supply is 24 volts, in most cases, it will not affect things at a first order level. However, because your first op-amp stage has a voltage gain of 4.3, it doesn't take much of a voltage level on Vin to cause limiting problems at the Vout node. Anything much above about 3.5 volts on the input is going to run into trouble here.